# How to take/save landscape snapshot using monkeyrunner on android?

Tags: python, monkeyrunner

Below is the way I am taking the screenshot and saving it on my local drive
    result = device.takeSnapshot()
    result.writeToFile('/Users/automation/test.png','png')

This saves the image as portrait is there a way to save as landscape?or the only option is to rotate using some other api?

Answer (score 0):

It's almost a one-liner using [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

from com.dtmilano.android.adb.adbclient import AdbClient

if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    serialno = sys.argv[1]
else:
    serialno = '.*'

AdbClient(serialno=serialno).takeSnapshot().rotate(90).save('/tmp/image.png')
```

The use of `adbclient` has been also explained at [adbclient: under the hood of AndroidViewClient/culebra](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2014/03/adbclient-under-hood-of.html).